# Ungreedy regular expressions

Tags: regex

I am referring a regular expression cheat sheet. 
It says

`{3,5}` means `3,4,and 5`

`{3,5}?` means `3,4,5` ungreedy +

what does `ungreedy +`indicate?

Comment: You're talking about [this cheat sheet](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/), aren't you?  Be aware that it's a mash-up of features drawn form many different flavors; so don't expect everything to work in your flavor of choice.  Also, it lists `(?!=...)` as an alternative syntax for negative lookbehind, which is just plain wrong.  Every flavor I'm familiar with uses `(?<!...)` if it supports lookbehinds at all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The quanitifier `{3,5}?` means that it will try to match 3 occurrences first, then see if the rest of the expression matches. If the rest of the expression fails it will backtrack and try 4, then finally 5.

The greedy version `{3,5}` will try the matches in the opposite order - longest first.

Note that greediness does not affect whether or not a string matches. It only affects the order in which the engine performs the search, and the contents of the captures if there are capturing groups.

Here's an example that demonstrates the difference. Imagine you have the string `aaaaabc`.

- `(a{3,5})(\w*)` will capture `aaaaa` and `bc`. [(rubular)](http://rubular.com/r/dPXPRdZnos)
- `(a{3,5}?)(\w*)` will capture `aaa` and `aabc`. [(rubular)](http://rubular.com/r/lFrahwxpjX)